# Why does Bundler.require load the wrong path?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, bundler

I'm having a problem with Bundler and Sinatra. First i used this in my app.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'redis'
...
```

However I read about `Bundler.require` and thought it's a nice DRY way because the gems specified in Gemfile are the ones I *will require* in my app anyway. Why should I specify the requires again in `app.rb`? So I changed my code to:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)
```

Much nicer huh? Not until problem ensues:

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory - /home/lamnk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/views/index.haml
file: tilt.rb location: read line: 119
```

Clearly bundler has moved the app's root path to its own. But why is that?

Comment: you can change the view path using "set :views, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/view'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old answer:

Take a look at ["using the rubygems bundler for your app"](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/using-the-rubygems-bundler-for-your-app/) on the Engine Yard blog.

New answer:

As Lamnk pointed out, that post on Engine Yard is old; so I made a simple app https://github.com/sinetris/sinatra-example-bundler

Comment: The post is quite old, require_env is not there anymore and it does not explain my problem.